# Decomposition of regular representation

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a compact group. Then there is an isomorphism $L^2(G)\simeq \bigoplus_{\tau\in \hat{G}} V_{\tau}\otimes V_{\tau^*}$ which intertwines the conjugation action of $G\times G$ on $L^2(G)$
$$C(g_1, g_2)f (x)=f(g_1^{-1}xg_2)=L(g_1)R(g_2)f (x)$$
and the $G\times G$ action on sum of $V_{\tau}\otimes V_{\tau^*}$ spaces defined by
$$A(g_1, g_2)(v\otimes f)= \tau(g_1)v\otimes \tau^*(g_2)f$$
for each pure tensor $v\otimes f\in V_{\tau}\otimes V_{\tau^*}$.

(Here $\tau^*$ denotes the dual of the representation $\tau$.)

Upon restriction of this intertwiner to $e\times G$ I expect to get an isomorphism
$$R\simeq \bigoplus_{\tau\in \hat{G}}1_{\tau}\otimes \tau^*$$
for the right regular representation.

However, I have seen this isomorphism being written differently as 
$$R\simeq \bigoplus_{\tau\in \hat{G}}\tau\otimes 1_{\tau^*}.$$

Can someone, please, clarify which version is correct and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your notation, you get the second isomorphism by restricting to $G\times \{e\}$, the left regular representation, and not the right regular one.  But the two representations are isomorphic via the map $x\to x^{-1}$; therefore, there is no conflict.

Note also that while your notation makes the first isomorphism more immediately believable, there no sense in which it is 'canonically' better; just note that switching $g_1$ and $g_2$ compatibly in the definitions of both $C$ and $A$, you get the other isomorphism for the right regular representation.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was guessing but still wanted someone to confirm it. I found it confusing because I knew that $\tau$ and $\tau^*$ are not equivalent representations. (The natural candidate for intertwining them is anti-linear rather than linear). So only looking at the right hand-sides it seems that the two decompositions should be nonequivalent in general. But as you said left and right regular representations are equivalent. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sam Yes, if by equivalent you mean isomorphic as $G$-representations, which is probably what you mean :)